# Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-services

I have rendering a ngxtoaster in angular 5 with core project (using webpack).

After rendering toaster i got a run time error:

> Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

I have changing the asp-ng2-prerendering in index file, But not working.

How to resolve this & why this error happens?

Comment: Have you tried declare const window: any;

Comment: where it will be declare? inside constructor or outside?